# Display only WEEKDAY from a range of dates

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services

I have the following queries in my SSRS:

```
SELECT [ARRIVED DATE]
FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[zWMGWEEKARRIVAL]
WHERE [ARRIVED DATE] = DATEPART(weekday,CAST([ARRIVED DATE] as float))
```

Which is supposed to get the ARRIVED DATE field and only display the weekday dates but I am receiving an `Explicit conversion from data type date to float is not allowed`

My  ARRIVED DATE looks like this:

```
2014-04-01
2014-04-02
2014-04-03
2014-04-04
2014-04-05
2014-04-06
2014-04-07
```

How do I modify my script so it only shows the weekday from those dates range.

Comment: what exactly you want the resultset to be?

Comment: 4/5 and 4/6 are weekend and I want to eliminate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the where clause to exclude Sunday and Saturday.  The SQL server defaults to a Sunday start so the below query should work for you in that case.

```
SELECT [ARRIVED DATE]
FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[zWMGWEEKARRIVAL]
WHERE DATEPART(weekday,[Arrived Date]) NOT IN (1,7)
```